# My neural network algorithm for a game is always moving the characters into corners

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, neural-network, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm fairly new to neural networks. After watching tutorials on how to build some, I decided to make a neural net in python to play my own game. In the game, there are hunters and prey all with neural networks (in the form of matrix multiplication). Hunters can collide with prey, eat them and then gain more life. To learn, the network chooses a couple of the best hunters and prey, selects a couple of the hunters and prey with a lower fitness, and then makes children of the best hunters and prey. The code works, but all the prey and the hunters go into the corners and I'm not exactly sure how to stop this. I want them to be more interactive. I've tried changing the matrices, adding biases, etc. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to take a look at how you are defining your loss function. If your neural network is implemented correctly and you have allocated enough weights; we should see your loss decrease over training iterations. If your loss teeters off to near zero yet your neural network isn't behaving as you want, you should penalize behavior that you do not want. For example, penalize hunters if they are idle (basically starve them).

Without knowing what kind of neural network you implemented, and how you interact with the environment (the output of the neural network) I can't give you much more specifics beyond that.